# How can I disable DLL Caching in Windows Vista via CMD?

Tags: windows-vista, command-prompt

I know Windows Vista (and XP) cache recently loaded DLL's in memory...

How can this be disabled via the command prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing you can do is disable SuperFetch, which can be done from the command prompt with this command (there has to be a space between the = sign and disabled).

```
sc config Superfetch start= disabled
```

There is a myth out there that you can disable DLL caching, but that only worked for systems prior to Windows 2000. [[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776795.aspx)]

Comment: The only thing that tweak ever did was disable _Explorer_'s caching of DLLs. This was necessary for developers working on Explorer plugins - without it Explorer would keep old versions of the plugin DLLs mapped, making them difficult to replace with new versions for testing. That this tweak was specific to Explorer is indicated by the fact that it's found in a subkey under Explorer's key in the registry. It had nothing to do with caching of DLLs in general. DLLs may be prefetched but other than that they are demand-paged like all other code (except nonpageable kernel mode code).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be helpful to know why you want to do this and then try to help solve the original problem...

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not cache recently used DLLs in memory.

It does cache the contents of the files in the file cache, like it would normally do with data files.